# How to make my databaseconnect class to allow for concurrent use

Tags: java, class, concurrency, thread-safety, database-connection

I have create a class called `databaseconnect` which is responsible for:
connecting to database, method for filling combobox, method for authentification, method for insert, remove, modify,....

The problem I am having is that I can actually use this class only once.

For example, I have created a `JFrame` called **Login**, in this JFrame i use "databaseconnect" to call its method `authentification`.

In another `JFrame` I am calling "databaseconnect" to fill a combobox and fill data in a table.

But when i use "`databaseconnect`" multiple times the program stops running.

here is an example of the code:

1- `Login` form:

```
 private void LoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    con=new databaseconnect();
    String a=u.getText();
    String b=pas.getText();
    con.authentification(a,b); 
    this.setVisible(false); 
}
```

2- in another class called `Client`:

```
public Client() {
  databaseconnect con= new databaseconnect();
 initComponents();

          con.opencn();
       con.fillcombo(combobox);
  }
```

now when i run this program it does not open

3- Database connect:
    `Databaseconnect` class:

```
public class databaseconnect extends Login 
{



Admin ad=new Admin();


Client cl= new Client();


String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/bookstore";
String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

String user="root";
String pass="root";
Connection cn;

public void opencn()
{
try
    {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        cn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
          System.out.println("Connected To Database");        
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
           System.out.println("Error Connecting To Database");

    }
}
public void authentification(String a, String b)
{

   String sql="SELECT * from admin_login ";
      try{

         Statement stmt=cn.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);


         System.out.println(sql);
       String resultat="";
   while(rs.next()) 
     {
         System.out.println(a);
       System.out.println(b);
       String uname= rs.getString("username");
       String p= rs.getString("password");

         if ((uname.equals(a)) && (p.equals(b)))
         {

         System.out.println("Login Successful"); 

       ad.setVisible(true);

         }
         else{
             System.out.println("wrong username/password");
         }

     }
        }catch(Exception e)
    {
       System.out.println(e.getMessage());     
    }


   }
 public void fillcombo(JComboBox cmb)
{ String sql= "SELECT * from client";



    try{
        opencn();
    Statement st=cn.createStatement();

    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
    while(rs.next())
    {



        cmb.addItem(rs.getString("Client_Name"));
    }
      }catch(SQLException e){
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      }
           }

         }
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You may want to show your `databaseconnect` class anyway.  Have you tried to use step-by-step debugging to see if the program falls into an infinite loop or something of this sort?

Comment: ok please check the question again, i edited it and added the code for databaseconnect

Comment: `databaseconnect` extends `Login`. Does by any chance `Login form` belong to `Login` class?

Comment: never mind it i removed the extends login while ago i know it doesn't help, but still, it was working well, when i created the Client class and called " databaseconnect" it stopped working.

Comment: "now when i run this program **it does not open**"  What exactly do you mean here? And again, have you tried to run it **under debugger**?

Comment: i used the debugger, it says: No variables to display because there is no current thread.
what exactly happens is that the login form open, i enter the username and password and when i press the login button it keeps loading. nothing else happens. if i delete the " Client " class it works again.

Comment: Is there a limit on the database side on a number of concurrent log-ins for user "root"?

Comment: Another thought: your `databaseconnect` class instantiates `Client` (`Client cl= new Client();`) but `Client` itself instantiates `databaseconnect`.

Comment: removed it now, still nothing.
sry for disturbing u with question im new to java.
just one more thing... does the problem have anything to do with having to close a db connection and reopening it?

Comment: I have a feeling (not an actual knowledge) that your `databaseconnect` is not **thread-safe**.  Since my Java knowledge is still pretty shallow I'm afraid I'm out of ideas at the moment.  I will change your title and add tags in a hope to get more folks to look at your question.